# Prevent methods with empty bodies from deletion on save

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-7

It's quite a contradictory habit of mine to press Ctrl+S permanently. The negative side is that delphi deletes empty functions/procedures on save.

Is there a way to prevent IDE from deleting functions/procedures with empty bodies on save?

Comment: This happens with event handlers only. Write them without delay or comment them with *todo*

Comment: @user539484 please, post it as the answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Converted from the comment as per OP request. My comment is too tiny for an answer, so I'm going to add few details maybe already obvious to an OP.*

> This happens with event handlers only¹. Write them without delay or
>   comment them with *todo*²

¹ That is, [event handlers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Events) are methods of *design class* and they are created, listed and deleted (if caught empty when saving or compiling) by the *[form designer](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Form_Designer)* (this include data module designer and any of other custom designers installed). Confer to *delegates* you probably familiar with from C# background. Any other methods are subject to "manual" management.

² [TODO items](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Using_To-Do_Lists) (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+T</kbd> in default keybinding) are definitely better than just blank comments:

```
procedure TForm1.MagicButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  { TODO -ctomorrow : I'm going to write the code, I promise! }
end;
```

#### Possible special case

`TAction` with `AutoCheck` set **must** (see the comment from [Sir Rufo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1744164) below for another possibility at run time) have its `OnExecute` assigned in order to be `Enabled`. In this case it is inevitably to have such blank event handlers within *design class*. Example:

```
procedure TMonitor.AutoCheckActionExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // dummy stub
  { DONE -crefactor : merge with other stub(s) }
end;
```

Comment: Still lacks a link to the intro-level text about "design class" concept, tho. Know any?

Comment: There is no special case with TAction. Just set TAction.DisableIfNoHandler to false. But you have to that at runtime, because it is not a published property (just public)

Comment: @Sir Rufo, yep, and that unpublished property makes stub handler way a simplier one.

Comment: Agree with David and you. Don't do much forms programming anymore, but your approach is what I used to do as well.

Comment: @user539484 simplier - yes, must - no

Comment: @user539484, I do not work much with delphi. Nevertheless the project I inherited is written in delphi and all the developers who managed it, declared their methods as if they were *event handlers*....so every Ctrl+S influenced any of them as any event handler. I never noticed myself, that this behaviour did not take place for methods in `private` or `public` or `published` areas. You made me catch this. That's why your post is the answer to my question. Others get upvotes from me. This post was indeed informative. Thanks everyone a lot.

Comment: @Sir Rufo, you are indeed right, but I was trying to stick to design-time behaviours as per original question.

Comment: @Konstantin Vasilcov, be aware what making an event handler method non-`published` will break Delphi's form loading system. This is little beyond the scope of the original question, but **event handler method** will be bound at run-time to **event property** by the means of name lookup (stringly!) and this requires both of them to be `published` (see TObject.FieldAddress and TObject.MethodAddress).

Comment: @user539484 I didn't mean to change event handlers' access modifiers. Only "auxiliary" methods not bound to any form event. Before this post I didn't distinguish these two categories. Another thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Just add an empty comment like `//`

```
begin 
//
end;
```

an other way would by moving the declaration to the `published part`

```
type
  TForm5 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject); // will be removed if empty
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
  published
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject); // will not be removed if empty

    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;
```

Comment: I know this way, but actually I would be happy to know some IDE option to turn off this behaviour at all.

Comment: @Konstantin: I don't think there is any. (Other than patching some binaries, maybe. :-))

Comment: Hmm, I use the IDE's behavior to my benefit: If I want to DELETE an event handler, I just remove the code and save. Without this automagic behavior I'd need to: Delete the event block, delete it's declaration from the interface section, make a change to the DFM so that Delphi notices the event is no longer there, suffer through a number of error messages telling me the event handler is no longer there and needs to be removed from components. Also my "dummy" code is **twice** shorter! I only write `;`

Comment: Forgot to mention: this automatic behavior saves you from the trouble of deleting useles event handlers that get created when you mistakenly double-click the wrong component on a form, or when you mistakenly ctrl-enter the wrong event in object inspector. The single `;` is a fair price to pay, IMHO.

Comment: How I wish this feature would be available in VS (at least in pluginless Express edition I'm using).

Comment: Or just write `begin ; end;` which involves even less typing ;)

Comment: +1: very informative....thanks a lot...I've written my thoughts in comment under the answer by user539484

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a way to prevent IDE from deleting functions/
>   procedures with empty bodies on save?

There is no option in the IDE to disable this behaviour.

Comment: And if there might ever be one it will never make it into D7.

Comment: +1 full agree with Sir Rufo, this answer is the one fitting to the question.